# Store range values in a VBA object

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a procedure which multiplies values present in a specified range (`A1:B2`) by a value passed as a parameter (the value written in the cell `D1`).

Now, how can I do in order to run again the same macro with a different parameter that will operate on the original values? I'm pretty sure I need some global variable which will tell my procedure that the macro has been run at least one time (I found how to do it) but I don't know how/where to store the original values.

For example, I have

```
    Range("A1").Value = 1
    Range("A2").Value = 1
    Range("B1").Value = 1
    Range("B2").Value = 1
    Range("D1").Value = 2
```

Click the macro button and get the values in the range `Range("A1:B2")` as the following

```
    Range("A1").Value = 2
    Range("A2").Value = 2
    Range("B1").Value = 2
    Range("B2").Value = 2
```

Now, after manually editing the `Range("D1").Value` from `2` to `3` and clicking again the macro button i want my procedure return the following values

```
    Range("A1").Value = 3
    Range("A2").Value = 3
    Range("B1").Value = 3
    Range("B2").Value = 3
```

The minimalistic procedure could be structure as this

```
    dim rng as Range
    dim MyRange as Range
    set MyRange = Range("A1:B2")

    For each rng in MyRange
          rng.value = rng.value*Range("D1").Value
    next rng
```

I hope this is a good example. Thanks

Francesco

Comment: Its a good idea to provide the code as well.

Comment: Store the original values in either a VBA array, or on a worksheet, depending on your total requirements. (Or don't overwrite them at all). Also, please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, what you want is a way to track everytime you called your sub with the button and use this data within this very sub.

One way would be to create a public variable in a module (I usually create a variable module in my projects) and update this data in the sub you call with your button.

```
'Your public variable inside a module (VariablesModule)

 Public param() As Variant

'Your general code

 Call procedure(VariablesModule.param)

'Inside your sub

Sub procedure(byVal paramVal as Variant)
'(your code)
ReDim param(0 To n) As Variant
Set param(1) = ABCDEFG
End sub
```

A second way would be to simply store this data in a range and use/update it within your sub.

Comment: Hi, actually I don't know if we are talking about the same thing. For sure when you say "A second way would be to simply store this data in a range and use/update it within your sub" that's what I want to accomplish (that is the goal: store somewhere the original data). 
I've tried this option but it's very time consuming. I was wondering (i.e., I was googling) if it was possibile to let excel work in memory. 
Thank you  again

Comment: @Franco What you can do is store your orignal values in a constant/public variable (see my post) and operate on these variables instead of operating on the cells. This way, your "original" value isn't change once your procedure is called. (I hope i'm getting your question right but I feel like this i what oyu want to accomplish)

Comment: Thank you @Antoin.D . But, if you see my post, I thought it was the solution at theoritical level ( "I'm pretty sure I need some global variable [...] but I don't know how/where to store the original values") but I don't know how to practically implement it. 
What's the right object to initialize? An array? 
Could you write for "me" (the community) a scratch of code with the data I gave in the example? I just need the step of object initialization and the step which stores the data in it (I really apologize for any grammatical mistake)

Thank you very much

Comment: @Franco Here I modified my answer so it uses an array, you can now store N numbers of data entry wich in your case would represent a procedure call. And use them again anywhere in your code considering it's a public variable. Take note that the `Type` of data stored in your array is up to you so you can try to experiment with that to find the best option! :)

Comment: Also, see this link for a quick guide on Array in VBA https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/